# Ошибка с R: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

Добрый день!

У меня возникла ошибка, и не знаю, что сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста. Благодарю.

```
[2014-10-30 10:29:58 - Cipher] E:\Android\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-10-30 10:29:58 - Cipher] E:\Android\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
```

Answer (score 1):

В меню выберите Project - clean

Comment: Нет, не работаєт.

Answer (score 1):

- Откройте SDK менеджер и убедитесь, что "Android Support Library" в
  "Extras" установлено.
- Удалите  "appcompat_v7" из Eclipse и с диска
- Импортируйте библиотеку File -> Import -> Android(Existing Android
  Code into Workspace ->  Next
- Выберите корневую директорию
  **ADT_BUNDLE_INSTALLED_DIRECTORY\sdk\extras\android\support\v7**, жмите "Finish"

  Правой кнопкой на проекте -> "properties" и дальше:

  1. В секции "Android" в секции target "library" удалите старое и добавьте новый "appcompat_v7"
  2. В "Java Build Path" секции идём в "libraries" и удаляем всё, чего нет.
  3. В "Java Build Path" идите в "Order and Export" и выделите только эти пункты в таком порядке:

     - projectName/src
     - projectName/gen
     - Android Private Libraries
     - Android Dependecies
  4. В "Project References" выберите "appcompat_v7"